# Haskell map with parameters changing type?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, functional-programming

I am attempting to write my own function which takes an arbitrary number of tokens, and then splits an arbitrary string on any of those.

After a little bit of thinking, I believe I need to recursively iterate through a list of tokens, and then pass each split list into a map with the splitting function, followed by a flatten.

At present, my algorithm looks like so:

```
module MyAwesomeModule where

import qualified Data.Text as T

outputSplit :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
outputSplit s tokens = print $ splitRecursive tokens s

splitRecursive :: [String] -> String -> [String]
splitRecursive tokens s = splitOneOf tokens s

splitOneOf :: [String] -> String -> [String]
splitOneOf [] s = []
splitOneOf (t:tokens) s =  map (splitOneOf tokens)(map (T.unpack) (T.splitOn (T.pack t) (T.pack s))) ++ (splitOneOf tokens s)
```

Which errors out with:

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
Expected type: String -> String
  Actual type: String -> [String]
In the return type of a call of `splitOneOf'
In the first argument of `map', namely `(splitOneOf tokens)'
In the first argument of `(++)', namely
  `map
     (splitOneOf tokens)
     (map (T.unpack) (T.splitOn (T.pack t) (T.pack s)))'
```

So as far as I understand, what that means is that the `String`s in the initial split are being cast to `[Char]`

```
   Prelude > let a = (map (T.unpack) (T.splitOn (T.pack "a") (T.pack "abcdefabc")))
             ["","bcdef","bc"]
             :t a
             a::[String]
             let b = head a
             :t b
             b::String
```

Moreover, if `splitOneOf` is defined as:

```
    splitOneOf :: [String] -> String -> [String]
    splitOneOf [] s = []
    splitOneOf (t:tokens) s =  (map (T.unpack) (T.splitOn (T.pack t) (T.pack s))) ++ (splitOneOf tokens s)
```

then

```
   Prelude > let a = splitOneOf ["a", "b"] "abcdefghij"
             ["", "bcdefghij"]
             map (splitOneOf ["b"]) a
             [[""], [[""],["cdefghij"]]
```

What exactly is going on with the type signatures here? Is this the right way to map? What am I missing?

Comment: Why does map have three arguments? Did you mean to put `splitOneOf tokens` in parantheses?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I've modified the question accordingly

Comment: There's no need to use Data.Text. There is Data.List.Split.

Comment: that's kinda neat. But say I wanted to roll my own for practice purposes? How would I map a function onto itself?

Comment: You want to use `concatMap` and `splitOn` to get something of type `String -> [String] -> [String]` (first argument is a token). Then use a common recursion encapsulating function to repeatedlt apply this to a list if tokens.

Comment: after @user3217013 helped me with the initial problem I have rephrased my problem

Comment: `String`==`[Char]` - it's a type synonym.

Comment: so what am I missing? Why is the code not working?

Comment: You are missing two things. (===1===). If you want to apply an action several times, you better make its input and output the same type. Your action is "split a string on a given token" but its input is a `String` and the output is a `[String]`. You need to adapt it such that it both accepts and emits `[String]`. (===2===) When your list of tokens is empty, you are returning `[]` which is wrong. You have no actions to apply so you need to just return the input list. Otherwise your recursion will always end up returning `[]`.

Comment: Also please use this notation: @AbrahamP when replying to a specific user, otherwise that user may miss your reply.

Comment: @n.m. thank you for pointing out the problem with the typing. I'm currently rethinking my algorithm to take that into account. On the second point, while I do understand that the nested most level of recursion will simply return an empty list all the way up through the stack, I am struggling to figure out how to return the original list? Is there a way to have a pattern match to a noop?

Comment: `splitOneOf [] ss = ss` (take into account that input and output are of the same type). When you figure out `splitOneOf` you do very much want to find out which standard Prelude function you can use instead. It is important.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Control.Monad ((>=>))
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

--|Using list monad, for repeated concatMaps
splitOnMany :: [String] -- ^ delimiters
            -> String   -- ^ input
            -> [String] -- ^ output
splitOnMany [] = return
splitOnMany (d:ds) = splitOn d >=> splitOnMany ds
```

This list monad is usually thought of as some sort of a poor man's non-determinism or logic monad.  But, any time you need to do recursive flattening of lists, it can be used.  Here, we split on the first delimiter, then split all of those on the second delimiter, etc. and then flatten everything.  I'm pretty sure the explicit recursion isn't really necessary either.  The following is more generic, and might even optimize better:

```
import Control.Monad ((>=>))
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

splitOnMany :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOnMany = foldr (>=>) return . map splitOn
```

Comment: I think the list monad monad only obscures the matters here, it's really just `splitonMany tokens line = foldr (concatMap . splitOn) [line] tokens`.

Comment: For yours, why not foldl'?  For mine, the additional strictness doesn't help.  I think mine inlines better, since it is point-free.  You are right that the Kleisli fish probably isn't too clarifying; maybe I've just been thinking in monads too much lately.